# BIRT Reports and boolean parameters

Tags: java, birt

Strings parameters seem to be passed just fine with RenderTask.setParameterValue() but boolean parameters are always false.

Is there anything i need to know about boolean parameters here?

params['name'].value is always false

I tried primitive which should be autoboxed but also the Boolean wrapper explicitly.

Comment: You should post the java code fragment where setParameterValue() is invoked

Answer (score 0):

The problem came up when i split the RunAndRenderTask usages to RunTask and RenderTask. So by setting the parameters earlier on the RunTask instead of RenderTask was the logical thing to do.